# What service to use for deploying my flask + dash application

Tags: heroku, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, plotly-dash

I am building a small application with dash and flask. Where my user can upload his csv/excel file and have a look at the graphs being generated.
I assume the size of each excel file could be around hardly 50MB max / week.

I have '**ZERO**' knowledge on servers and deployment etc. Can anyone guide or enlighten me on this area. Also this application is just for an internal purpose so we are not allowed to go easy on the budget.

My random google searches gave me options like,
1. AWS
2. Heroku

Which would be a right option and why ? Considering price and ease of use.

Thanks !

Comment: You shouldn't have any difficulty doing this on the default recommendation – heroku

Answer (score 0):

I will share some of mine web dev knowledge, so.. in my company we use flask for all server dev, using many of his libs(like marshmallow, sqlalchemy, etc) and making improvements to them, flask offers you a big flexibility and fast development, but your request thread is poor, so i highly recommend to use a load balancer, the most famous load balancer for flask is Gunicorn, is easy to set and use. For Http server we use Nginx, its like Apache, but make to work with Websockets more easy, and to use with Gunicorn just make a proxy. For the Host, we use AWS, and work very fine for big and little applications, but your application is small and your budget too, so i recommend use the pythonanywhere server, its easy to use and optimized for python webservers. And for frontend we use Vue.js framework, makes our page more beautiful and fast to dev.