# Apache with Flask executes the whole Webapp.py file everytime a request is hit to the Webapi

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I already have an apache server that's configured and running successfully in the background.
However, there are some files that I am initliaizing outside my Flask function call but whenever a request is sent to it via Postman, it executes the whole Webapp.py file where my Flask functions are stored.

Is there any way in which I don't have to load the CSV file again and again when the service is called via Postman?

## Sample Webapp.py file below

```
app=Flask(__name__)

file=pd.read_csv('Filename.csv')
file1=pd.read_csv('Filename1.csv')

@app.route('/Index')
def function(methods=['GET','POST']):
     if request.method=='POST':
        response=Function_call()
     
     return response

app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Hi, i really  not recommend to use mod-wsgi/Apache in release server, because mod-wsgi is really limited when you work with many requests, and Apache not Work well with Websockets, so i recommend to take a look in Gunicorn insted mod-wsgi, and Nginx insted Apache

Comment: But the functionality that I asked in the question is possible in Nginx?
Where in I won't have to reload my .csv files again and again when a request is sent?

Comment: yep, i make global files to use in SKLearn form machine learn, and they work very well. If you wanna more details of my comment, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60069622/what-service-to-use-for-deploying-my-flask-dash-application/60076270#60076270